# What are Approximate Read Counts (Library Sizes) and Lengths (Insert Sizes) for Next-Generation DNA Sequencers?

Tags: ngs, metagenome, reads, illumina

I am performing a simulation study and am curious about the parameters of my simulated metagenome.

What are the library and insert sizes of some of the most "used" sequencers. Mainly, I am interested in the different Illumina platforms (MiSeq, HiSeq, HiSeqX), 454 Pyrosequencing, and Ion Torrent.

I do not need the long read technologies like Pac-Bio's SMRT and Oxford Nanopore since they are not typically used with metagenomics, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library size depends usually on your budget. There are some reviews where they compare the different platforms, but these papers get outdated so quickly, that it would be better to just check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_sequencing#Next-generation_methods) for the specs of different platforms. Also on the websites of Illumina or Life Tech, you'll find the specs.

NB. 454 sequencing is discontinued, so that is not very relevant anymore in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the Wiki link. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Both of those depend on the application of the library.  For example whole genome assembly of a mammal would require a larger library size than targeted re-sequencing of a virus.  Also insert size varies if you are doing genome assembly a larger insert size is valuable to allow for long range linking and scaffolding.

I think that if you edit your question of be more specific people will be able to provided a more concrete answer other wise it is "it depends"